# Why false value is returned even after data is saved successfully?

Tags: cakephp

In a cakephp Model, I have this code:-

```
class ApplyRequest extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'ApplyItem';

    public function saveItemTrip($sender_id, $carrier_id, $item_id, $trip_id, $applied_by, $applied_to)
    {
        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO apply_items (sender_id, carrier_id, item_id, trip_id, applied_by, applied_to)
                        VALUES ('$sender_id', '$carrier_id', '$item_id', '$trip_id', '$applied_by', '$applied_to')";
        if($this->query($queryInsert))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }   
}
```

Now, from the controller, I am calling the function:-

```
$isSuccess = $this->ApplyRequest->saveItemTrip($senderId, $memberId, $itemId, $getLastInsertID, $memberId, $senderId);
if($isSuccess)
{
    $status = "1";
    $message = "Trip-Request was successfull for this item";
}
else
{
    $status = "3";
    $message = "Error occured while applying for the item";
}
```

Now, the data is getting saved in the apply_items query. However, I am always getting the $status as 3.

it seems, $isSuccess is returned as false, for which I am getting status as 3.

What am I doing wrong?

### Note

I have to write this query in such custom fashion. There is a whole lot of reason, which I can't explain here elaborately.

Comment: what is the result of the query, have you debugged it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have to escape your variables in the insert statement.

```
$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO apply_items (sender_id, carrier_id, item_id, trip_id, applied_by, applied_to)
                    VALUES ('".$sender_id."', '".$carrier_id."', '".$item_id."', '".$trip_id."', '".$applied_by."', '".$applied_to."')";
```